# Delete specific entries from a column

Tags: mysql

I already read the mysql wiki but didn't get an answer how to delete specific entries from all rows in a column.

Let's say there's a column Example.
In Example the .php wrote: "One, Two, Three, Four, Five, Six"
And you want to delete Two and Six in all rows of the column.
I don't get it how to delete those entries without having multiple commas. (Multiple commas = "One,, Three")

Thanks in Advance

Comment: what have you tried so far? Share us the SQL query

Comment: I already tried: DELETE FROM database2
WHERE column3 = 'Six'; - That deletes the whole row

Comment: Comma separated values should not be in your database, it violates the [Zero, One or Infinity Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) of [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). This operation would be trivial if you have proper relational data, a one-to-many relationship in this case, as you could just delete the row you don't want.

Comment: Also keep in mind it's `DELETE FROM table_name`, not database. Deleting from the database makes no sense without a table for context.